# SharePoint Search issue resolving result source by name through API

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-search

During last weeks we are experiencing some issues on different tenants with Search in SharePoint.
We are doing requests to the API to search and we are providing the result source name.
During this last days, SharePoint seems that is not resolving properly the result source.
For instance...

https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27*%27&rowlimit=30&selectproperties=%27Path%2cUrl%2cTitle%2cAuthor%2cWrite%2cServerRedirectedEmbedURL%2cWorkId%27&clienttype=%27WebService%27&properties=%27SourceLevel:SPSiteSubscription,SourceName:Local%20People%20Results%27

it is being resolved as...
[image]

but in another tenant, where we don't have the issue, we have...
[image]

Is anyone else having this issue?
Is there any official MS issue opened or workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are also experiencing this in a number of our customer tenants. We can't track down what's exactly causing it. It seems to be different in each tenant.

But what does seem consistent is when we are referencing a custom Result Source.

Sometimes it works in the Result Source Query Editor and in some tenants that gives us an error message.  We are opening a ticket with Microsoft.

Did you make an further progress in your investigations?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, unfortunately, I haven't progress too much... on one of the tenants that was failing last week Local People Results, today is working, but today, the custom ones started to fail... so even worst. More and more customers are noticing the same today, so definetly something that is being roll out, is causing the issue.

We are opening a MS ticket on each of the tenants...

Comment: I have a bit more information. It appears that when we pass the SourceName property in the search query we get an error, but if we replace that with the sourceid then it DOES work.

This works
https://thisisattollo.sharepoint.com/sites/halo/_api/search/query?sourceid=%274e4259b7-4c16-4080-8cc9-614d12f22008%27

This doesn't work:
https://thisisattollo.sharepoint.com/sites/halo/_api/search/query?properties=%27SourceName:Attollo Other News,SourceLevel:SPSite%27

Comment: We also have some customers where there search service seems to be totally down as well.

Comment: So, it appears that the "properties" querystring is being totally ignored by the Search API.

Comment: No update for now... MS investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some weeks, this was solved by MS.
So, just as a suggestion, open tickets from all tenants where you could reproduce this kind of issues and try to speak with them to merge those cases.
Thanks